# acces routeUrl property value from inside component class

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a menu made of items like this

```
<nav-list>
  <nav-item routeUrl="/foo">
  <nav-item>
  <nav-item routeUrl="/bar">
  <nav-item>
</nav-list>
```

How can I access the value of `routeUrl` from inside a `nav-item` component ? 
I would like to compare that value against the current url to apply styles conditionaly to the item.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

> The RouterLinkActive directive on each anchor tag helps visually distinguish the anchor for the currently selected "active" route. The router adds the active CSS class to the element when the associated RouterLink becomes active. You can add this directive to the anchor or to its parent element.

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/crisis-center" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>
    <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Good one with the routerLinkActive. Whenever they smuggled that one into the API.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if your nav-item is a component you wrote, you need to work with `@Input`:

```
<nav-item [routeUrl]="'/foo'">
```

Note the quotes surrounding your `routeUrl` value and the square brackets around the directive. In your `NavItemComponent` you need to tell Angular about your input directive:

```
@Input() routeUrl:string;

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.routeUrl);
}
```

Note, that `@Input` decorated variables are not available in your constructor.